# How to style the element at the edge of a horizontal scroll menu

Tags: javascript, css

I came across [this](https://media1.giphy.com/media/4bCSSENdIaGCCXjnNc/giphy.gif) concept UI design of an image Gallery. Is there any way to achieve this using JavaScript?

Comment: Yes it is. Many image slider libraries even support this format. If you also want the background sliding you'll probably have to create a custom solution but it's definitely possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two libraries. I have imported......

```
EXTERNAL CSS
https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.css

EXTERNAL JAVASCRIPT
https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.js
```

Study following code and get the idea,

```css
/* external css: flickity.css */

* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.carousel {
  background: black;
}

.carousel-cell {
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  /* flex-box, center image in cell */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display:         flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.carousel-cell img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  /* dim unselected */
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.85);
          transform: scale(0.85);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
          filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s, transform 0.3s, -webkit-filter 0.3s, filter 0.3s;
          transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s, filter 0.3s;
}

/* brighten selected image */
.carousel-cell.is-selected img {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-filter: none;
          filter: none;
}

@media screen and ( min-width: 768px ) {
  .carousel-cell {
    height: 400px;
  }
}

@media screen and ( min-width: 960px ) {
  .carousel-cell {
    width: 60%;
  }
}

/* buttons, no circle */
.flickity-prev-next-button {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.flickity-prev-next-button:hover {
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 1;
}
/* arrow color */
.flickity-prev-next-button .arrow {
  fill: white;
}
.flickity-prev-next-button.no-svg {
  color: white;
}
/* closer to edge */
.flickity-prev-next-button.previous { left: 0; }
.flickity-prev-next-button.next { right: 0; }
/* hide disabled button */
.flickity-prev-next-button:disabled {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.js"></script>
<link href="https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Flickity HTML init -->
<div class="carousel js-flickity">
  <!-- images from unsplash.com -->
  <div class="carousel-cell">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/orange-tree.jpg" alt="orange tree" />
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg" alt="submerged" />
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/look-out.jpg" alt="look-out" />
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/one-world-trade.jpg" alt="One World Trade" />
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/drizzle.jpg" alt="drizzle" />
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/cat-nose.jpg" alt="cat nose" />
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/contrail.jpg" alt="contrail" />
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/golden-hour.jpg" alt="golden hour" />
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/flight-formation.jpg" alt="flight formation" />
  </div>
</div>
```